# Unable to upload file using selenium java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

I try to upload a pic on this site but exception comes up. Here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "I:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
     JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    driver.get("https://jpg2png.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    js.executeScript("window.scroll(0,100)");


    WebElement Pic=driver.findElement(By.id("pick-files"));
    String js1 = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";

    Pic.sendKeys("D:\\University Work\\6th Semester\\IAP\\outline.jpg");

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

The browser open website also open but uploading doesn't happen. type="file" is also not there in html code.
The Exception is:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Comment: You write "but exception comes up".. adding the exception to the description stacktrace would greatly help solve the problem.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Comment: post the HTML markup for the upload form.

Comment: For the sake of debugging, does a Thread.sleep(5000) before "driver.findElement(By.id("pick-files"))" solve the problem? (If yes, don't use Thread.sleep in your test, rather use FluentWait from Selenium to wait until the element is available.)

Answer (score 0):

try to click on upload button. As of now you enter a path to a file you want to upload but not clicking upload button